# windows suddenly can't run python "this app can't run on your PC anymore"

Tags: python, windows, windows-10

I was coding on VSCODE and when I wanted to run the script I suddenly got thrown this error by windows [image]

so now if I type python on cmd I get this error and python returns "Access is denied."
this happened suddenly so one minute I could run python and now I can't, so I don't think it's a windows update causing a problem

I looked around and it seems most people that get this error downloaded 32bit version of an app on a 64bit machine

edit: it seems like python.exe now is 0kb it's corrupted so I'll probably have to reinstall python but I'd love to know what caused it.

Comment: It's Windows... you've tried rebooting?

Comment: of course I did

Comment: Nothing is "of course" here. If you didn't tell us, it didn't happen. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I've run into all kinds of issues in VSCode. If you can, take a look at something like Atom or Sublime Text. I've found them to be a lot less fussy.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. I code almost exclusively in python, and it works just fine in Atom and Sublime Text. See this handy article on how to set up Sublime Text, for instance: [link](https://realpython.com/setting-up-sublime-text-3-for-full-stack-python-development/)

Comment: the python executable got corrupted, so cmd python doesn't work, I think the culprit in corrupting the exe is probably VSCode

Comment: All the more reason not to use VSCode. I'd re-install Python to repair it, install dependencies, and run a different editor.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into same issue. Try downloading "Windows x86-64 MSI installer" from this link https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/ for Windows. This one worked for me.

This is the latest 2.X version as of writing this answer. To future check the 2.X latest release if any from the default download page of python.